# Breaking a cell if it contains a newline character

Tags: excel

In Excel, I want to be able to automatically break a cell into 2 or more cells if they contain a newline character (alt + Enter). How do I do this so that it'll divide the cell into new cells below that row?

Comment: I won't be able to help regardless, but for people who know Excel, it might help if you specify how you are interfacing with it. COM?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub MakeTwoCellsForCellHavingLF()
Dim currentCellValue As String, LFFoundAt As Integer

currentCellValue = ActiveCell.Value
LFFoundAt = InStr(1, currentCellValue, vbLf)

If LFFoundAt <> 0 Then
    ActiveCell.Value = Left(currentCellValue, LFFoundAt - 1)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Value = Mid(currentCellValue, LFFoundAt + 1)
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your data is in A1.

A2 should contain (Please excuse and delete the C-style comments.):

```
=FIND(CHAR(10),A1) // Location of CHAR(10), your newline.
```

[ASCII](http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html) 10 means newline. Hide Row 2.

A3 should contain:

```
=IF(
    NOT(ISERR(A2)), // Make sure there is a newline
    LEFT(A1, A2-1), // Everything up to the newline
    A1              // If there's no newline, original string
   )
```

A4 should contain:

```
=IF(
    NOT(ISERR(A2)),        // Make sure there is a newline
    RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-A2), // Everything after the newline
    ""                     // If there's no newline, nothing
   )
```